# Set width for displayed code chunk in R Markdown presentation

Tags: r, r-markdown, slide, presentation

I want to set width for displayed code chunk in R Markdown presentation. In the simple example I put below, the code line `ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = value)) +` is wrapped in two lines in the presentation. My goal is to:

1. (primarily) have it not getting wrapped,
2. set a width for displayed code chunk, ideally, with the use of slide width percentage (%).

R Makrdown code:

````
Presentation title
========================================================
author: Marta 
date: February 9, 2019
autosize: true

Simple plot 
==========================

<small><small><small>
```{r, fig.width = 10, fig.height = 5}
## Make some foo data frame
df <- data.frame(time = 1:10, value = rnorm(10))

## Plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = value)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line()
```
</small></small></small>
````

A slide screenshot from a rendered presentation:

[image]

Comment: How exactly and to what (pdf or html) do you want to knit this?

Comment: Hi @jay.sf , I am planning to output it as HTML (via "Save as Web Page..." RStudio button).